# Obtaining sha1 Signature of eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I am fairly new with android and I am trying to work with Maps. I need to get the sha-1 for the eclipse keystone but i don't seem to know the location of the signature of the file eclipse uses. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the default key eclipse uses for signing its application. You can find the eclipse debug key for signing your application on `userhome/.android/.debug.keystore`. You can use keytool command pointing to that debug.keystore file

Here is a sample command and a sample output

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

And the output

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jan 27, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 5104c86e
Valid from: Sun Jan 27 12:10:50 NPT 2013 until: Tue Jan 20 12:10:50 NPT 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  3B:D1:03:....
     SHA1: 46:CB:E4:69:C0:....
     SHA256: 4C:D8....
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

For registering your maps with your signing key signature, you need to do the same with your signature. Please read more on [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) for explained article. Hope this helped :)

Comment: Oh, dint realise the android folder was hidden, I was looking for it. Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found my signature for the default keystore. In Eclipse, if you go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build

[image]

Comment: You can find out it easily in eclipse itself @user3619542

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get it :  In Eclipse, if you go to Windows ->
Preferences -> Android -> Build